# get total of dynamic clone rows

Tags: jquery

I'm doing jquery based order sheet.
As i searched similar question, there are hundreds of way to get total value of each TABLE ROW.
But in my case, Total value fires strange way.

Full source code is uploaded to jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/pR9Qd/

There are two main problem.

1. Total value of .total_amount is strange. it's bigger than sum of each .amount
2. When i delete some rows, the .total_amount won't changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem with remove row is no calculations being done:

```
function RemoveRow(htmlelement) {
    $(htmlelement).parent().parent().remove();
   /* after remove, run calcs again*/
    doCalc();
}
```

I worked on demo and cleaned it up quite a bit. It is not a full application yet, but a lot closer. Use of $.each for finding input elements was not correct at all. Syntax was wrong, order of chaining find() was wrong. First find the elemenet collection, then run `each`.

Math seems OK when remove the `<?=$dollar_value?>` and `+15000` so can see simple numbers adding.
`Add row` and `delete row` working now. `Add row` was not resetting values of cloned row

DEMO : http://jsfiddle.net/pR9Qd/1/

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. Then where can i input calculation with <?=$dollar_value?> ...

Comment: It apply currency exchange rate to the each .amount and + 15000(it's extra fee). If i use $(this).find('span.amount').html((qty * <?=$dollar_value?> * price) + 15000); , div.total_amount seems to calculate with double "15000". How can i add extra fee on each .amount

Comment: OK...I took that out so could easily see small numbers working and the <?=$dollar_value?> was undefined in original demo- no php running, put it back same place

Comment: on the top of script php declare $dollar_value.

Comment: whatever works best for you... just breaks in non php envirnoment is all

Comment: It's strange but this works best. $(this).find('span.amount').html((qty * <?=$dollar_value?> * price) + 15000 );
        
    });
    $('.amount').each(function() {
        total += parseInt($(this).text(), 10);
    });
    $('div.total_amount').html(total - 15000);